# Time performance when permuting and casting double to float

Tags: c++

I have some big arrays given by MATLAB to C++ (therefore I need to take them as they are)  that needs casting and permuting (row-mayor, column mayor issues).

The array, `imgaux` is double type has size `size_proj[0]*size_proj[1]*size_proj[2]` and needs to be casted to float, changing some locations of values. A minimal example is as follows:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  
   int main(void){
      int size_proj[3];
    size_proj[0] = 512;
    size_proj[1] = 512;
    size_proj[2] = 360;
    size_t num_byte_double = size_proj[0] * size_proj[1] * size_proj[2] * sizeof(double);
    size_t num_byte_float = size_proj[0] * size_proj[1] * size_proj[2] * sizeof(float);

    double *imgaux = (double*) malloc(num_byte_double);
    float* img = (float*) malloc(num_byte_float);


    clock_t begin, end;
    double time_spent;

    begin = clock();
    for (int k = 0; k < size_proj[0]; k++)
        for (int i = 0; i <size_proj[1]; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < size_proj[2]; j++)
                img[i + k*size_proj[1] + j*size_proj[0] * size_proj[1]] = (float)imgaux[k + i*size_proj[0] + j*size_proj[0] * size_proj[1]];
    end = clock();
    time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Time permuting and casting the input %f", (float)time_spent);
    free(imgaux);
    free(img);
    getchar();
}
```

However, this is a huge performance bottleneck, taking up to 6 seconds for big arrays (512*512*300).

I know that if instead of doing the 3D indexing part, I'd be doing

```
for (int k = 0; k < size_proj[0]*size_proj[1]*size_proj[3]; k++)
      img[k]=(float)imgaux[k];
```

The code would be taking about 0.2 seconds to run. However, I need the "permutation" of the dimensions as in the first code snippet.

Is there a way I can speed up that code while still changing the values of place?

Comment: not enough information here to comment. can you set up a minimal, complete, compilable program so we can tinker with it?

Comment: Aren't you asking for a *fast* fortran to C memory ordering conversion?

Comment: Are `size_proj[0]` and `size_proj[1]` always the same? It looks this way from your algorithm...

Comment: @SimonKraemer not necessarily, it was just an example.

Comment: @RichardHodges Updated with MCVE

Comment: I have not read the question really, but if this is about `permute` and `reshape`, I could add few things. Not sure about mex/C level, but at MATLAB level generally speaking `permute` is a costly affair. So, use it sparingly. In comparison `reshape` is *mostly free*. So, the idea is use to minimal permutes, even if that means few more reshapes. And all of this would be logical I guess, because with permute, you are re-arranging elements in memory, whereas in reshape, there is no memory re-arrangement AFAIK.

Comment: @Divakar Thanks for the hint! However, in this case, its an unavoidable permute!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, let's unravel your loop a little bit by precalculating things ASAP:

```
int max0 = size_proj[0];
int max1 = size_proj[1];
int max2 = size_proj[2];

for (int k = 0; k < max0; k++)
{
    int kOffset1 = k*max1;
    int kOffset2 = k;

    for (int i = 0; i < max1; i++)
    {
        int iOffset1 = i;
        int iOffset2 = i*max0;

        for (int j = 0; j < max2; j++)
        {
            int jOffset1 = j*max0*max1;
            int jOffset2 = j*max0*max1;


            int idx1 = iOffset1 + jOffset1 + kOffset1;
            int idx2 = iOffset2 + jOffset2 + kOffset2;
            img[idx1] = (float)imgaux[idx2];
        }
    }
}
```

The calculation for `jOffset1/2` seems to be suboptimal being on the lowest level of your nested loop. This always makes the `idx1/2` value jump for `max0*max1` every iteration. So let's move this to the highest level:

```
int max0 = size_proj[0];
int max1 = size_proj[1];
int max2 = size_proj[2];
for (int j = 0; j < max2; j++)
{
    int jOffset1 = j*max0*max1;
    int jOffset2 = j*max0*max1;

    for (int k = 0; k < max0; k++)
    {
        int kOffset1 = k*max1;
        int kOffset2 = k;

        for (int i = 0; i < max1; i++)
        {
            int iOffset1 = i;
            int iOffset2 = i*max0;

            int idx1 = iOffset1 + jOffset1 + kOffset1;
            int idx2 = iOffset2 + jOffset2 + kOffset2;
            img[idx1] = (float)imgaux[idx2];
        }
    }
}
```

That already looks better. `kOffset1/2` and `iOffset1/2` can't be optimized anymore, but we still have unecessary values and declarations. Let's sum these up:

```
for (int j = 0; j < size_proj[2]; j++)
{
    int jOffset = j*size_proj[0]*size_proj[1];
    for (int k = 0; k < size_proj[0]; k++)
    {
        int kOffset1 = k*size_proj[1];
        for (int i = 0; i < size_proj[1]; i++)
        {
            int iOffset2 = i*size_proj[0];
            img[i + jOffset + kOffset1] = (float)imgaux[iOffset2 + jOffset + k];
        }
    }
}
```

---

I tried your updated MVCE with your loop and with mine (same system using MSVC14):

Yours:

> Time permuting and casting the input 4.180000

Mine:

> Time permuting and casting the input 0.704000

Hopefully I didn't mess anything up ;-)

---

As @BarryTheHatchet pointed out and as it is easily overseen in the comment section: Instead of using an array of 3 `int` values for `size_proj` you better use three `const int` values.

Not using an array will remove complexity from your code (using descriptive names of course) 
The use of `const` will prevent you from accidentially changing values in complex calculation and may allow the compiler for better optimization.

---

As @paddy pointed out: You may replace the multiplications at the different levels of your nested loop with calculations by precalculating the step sizes.

I had tried this but there wasn't any real change in the *multiplication* version and *step* version....

```
const int jStep     = size_proj[0] * size_proj[1];
const int jStepMax  = size_proj[0] * size_proj[1] * size_proj[2];
const int kStep1 = size_proj[1];
const int kStep1Max = size_proj[0] * size_proj[1];
const int kStep2 = 1;
const int kStep2Max = size_proj[0];
const int iStep1 = 1;
const int iStep1Max = size_proj[1];
const int iStep2 = size_proj[0];
const int iStep2Max = size_proj[0] * size_proj[1];

for (int jOffset = 0; jOffset < jStepMax; jOffset += jStep)
{
    for (int kOffset1 = 0, kOffset2=0; kOffset1 < kStep1Max && kOffset2 < kStep2Max; kOffset1+=kStep1, kOffset2+=kStep2)
    {
        for (int iOffset1 = 0, iOffset2 = 0; iOffset1 < iStep1Max && iOffset2 < iStep2Max; iOffset1 += iStep1, iOffset2 += iStep2)
        {
            img[iOffset1 + jOffset + kOffset1] = (float)imgaux[iOffset2 + jOffset + kOffset2];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just making some tests to corroborate that you didnt mess anything up, but wow, fantastic job really.

Comment: as @BarryTheHatchet suggests in the other asnwer, subsituting my array of ints by `const int` variables speeds this up to about half the time of your results!

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet Mind if update my answer with your `const int` suggestion?

Comment: There is no need to do all those multiplications.  You can just begin each offset at zero, and add the step size each iteration.  If the compiler is smart about this, it will be doing that anyway.

Comment: @SimonKraemer: By all means. `const` is your friend!

Answer (score 1):

In terms of the algorithm you're using, I think you're always going to end up with three nested loops.

Two things to think about:

- In your innermost loop, there's some values that you calculate every time, which don't change every iteration. The compiler may cache them, but maybe not, so try moving them to the highest possible scope.

  - `k * size_proj[1]`
  - `i * size_proj[1]`
  - `size_proj[0] * size_proj[1]` (and `j * size_proj[0] * size_proj[1]` is used twice)
- Think about how your arrays are laid out in memory. Is there a way you can reorder your loops so that you're reading and writing to continuous regions of memory as much as possible? You'll get fewer cache misses and better performance if you read and write to continuous regions.

Comment: I will think a bit more about 2, but your first point, while a good idea, speeds the code about 1%, which is not that much, unfortunately

Comment: Point #1 is valid but there's a better fix - make those values _constants_! An array of `int` for `size_proj` is needlessly complex.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in this example is cache locality. Looking at the assignment, the fastest-changing index is `j` but this has the largest effect on the address of the write in the target array:

```
img[i + k*size_proj[1] + j*size_proj[0] * size_proj[1]] =
```

Notice that j is multiplied by 2 constants. Every change in j is likely to cause the result to be written to a new cache line.

The solution is this case is to invert the order of the loops:

```
    const auto K = size_proj[0];
    const auto I = size_proj[1];
    const auto J = size_proj[2];
    for (int j = 0; j < J; j++)
        for (int i = 0; i < I; i++)
            for (int k = 0; k < K; k++)
                img[i + k * I  + j * K * I] = (float)imgaux[k + i * K + j * K * I];
```

Which (on my laptop) brings us down from:

```
Time permuting and casting the input 4.416232
```

to:

```
Time permuting and casting the input 0.844341
```

Which I think you'll agree is something of an improvement.